# Line breaks between buttons in jQuery dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jQuery dialog box with three buttons.

It looks like:
Would you like to proceed to the signup page?

```
          < More Info > < OK > < Cancel >
```

Is there any way to put a line break between buttons so that I end up with:
Would you like to proceed to the signup page?

```
                        < OK > < Cancel >
                            < More Info >
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dialogClass` option to add a custom class to the dialog and then write some CSS to style the s in a way that makes them appear one per line. The best method I've found is setting `float: none` and `clear: both`.

Comment: Can I add CSS to a particular button?  I only want a line break after cancel.  Not after OK.

Answer (score 1):

[Like this](http://jsbin.com/idila/):

```
$('#dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button:last').css('clear', 'both');
```

You'll also need to make the button last, not first.

Comment: After calling `.dialog()`.  See my sample: http://jsbin.com/idila/edit#javascript